# Get a static internet ip address

Tags: networking, ip

Whenever my router goes off my IP gets constantly changed, which is not favourable when running an online service. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Talk to your ISP.  That should be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most ISPs offer static IP as a service that comes with an extra cost. Talk to your ISP.